# google chrome add-ons

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons

I was able to install the same add-on in google chrome as in firefox.  Do chrome add-ons have to be made especially for chrome, or do all firefox add-ons work in chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox uses XUL (XML UI Language) and JavaScript to for extensions, however, chrome uses internet standards such as Jason, HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Development process are different, GUIs in both use 2 different technologies, although GUI-control technology is same (JavaScript), at least today there is no Firefox to chrome extension converter. Theoretically the conversion is possible but someone has to develop it, until that day one has to develop 2 separate extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they have to be made especially for Chrome, and no, Firefox add-ons don't work in Chrome.

Actually in Chrome they are called "extensions". And maybe it's possible to assemble the Chrome extension and the Firefox add-on in the same package? I guess that's what happened with your add-on? What particular add-on are you talking about?

I know that most of my Firefox add-ons already have a similar Chrome extension.
For instance [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) has both a [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8542) and a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd).

For more information regarding Chrome extensions, see [their official blog](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchrome.blogspot.com%2F+extensions).

Comment: There are also Greasemonkey scripts: they work unmodified in almost any browser including Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: They're called "extensions" in Firefox, too (which is why Chrome calls them that). "Addons" encompases extensions, themes, and plugins.